# reference and const reference returned from operator in C++

Tags: c++

I do not understand why we usually need two versions of functions that return reference - one const and the other not.
For example in this code:

```
const char& String::operator[](int index) const {
    verify_index(index);
    return data[index];
}

char& String::operator[](int index) {
    verify_index(index);
    return data[index];
}
```

if we only had const, then we wouldn't be able to do for example str[i] = value. But what is the problem with only having non-const reference, can someone please give an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you only had a nonconst overload, you would be unable to use the `[]` synax on `const` strings.

```
void print_first(const std::string& word) {
    std::cout << word[0]; //like this
}
```

If you have only the `const` overload, you would be unable to use the `[]` syntax to modify the string:

```
void edit_first(std::string& word) {
    word[0] = 'a';
}
```

If you made a `const` overload that returns a mutable char, that's even worse!

```
void edit_first(const std::string& word) {
    word[0] = 'a'; //wait, I thought word was const?
}
```

It's a frustration that you have to add two overloads, but usually 90% of the code can be shared (as you did with `verify_index`), or they end up being just two-liners.

(There is a fourth combination of a nonconst overload that returns a const char, but that's harmless and mostly useless so... yeah.)

Answer (score 1):

```
const String s = "abc";

cout << s[0]; // Ooops! Cannot run operator[] because no const qualifier.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two instances of the `const` keyword in your example and you seem to be ignoring the second one, the one that allows you to call the operator on a `const` instance.